# Condense Cognito form for printing

Tags: cognito-forms

We receive email copies of the forms received from our site. We need to print this email copy out for particular reasons. However, the form is quite spread out when it prints. Is there any way of condensing the format that gets emailed to us?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently, as the email format in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) is specifically designed to work on a variety of different email clients (especially phones) and it is difficult to produce a condensed view that responds well in all of these cases.

However, you can print entries from administration using the Print button, which is a much more condensed format similar to the form when filled out, but read-only with all information viewable.  Also, we are working on [PDF & Word Merging](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy) to allow you to generate custom printable PDF and Word documents in any format you want, and this feature will include support for attaching these to email notifications and confirmations.